# Why is UIBarButtonItem's target set to nil when initializing with init(barButtonSystemItem, target, action)?

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, uibarbuttonitem

This initializer

```
convenience init(barButtonSystemItem systemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem, 
      target: Any?, 
      action: Selector?)
```

[according to the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617153-init) accepts a *target* and then in the return section they explain that it is actually set to *nil*. Why do they do it?

And I mean they actually do it because it was the thing that drove me crazy and I had to write code like this:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {


    let pauseItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .pause, target: self, action: #selector(GameViewController.pauseButtonTouchUp))
    let playItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .play, target: self, action: #selector(GameViewController.pauseButtonTouchUp))



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.pauseItem.target = self
        self.playItem.target = self

        . . . 
}
```

Because otherwise the action would not be triggered. Why did they decide it was a good idea to accept a parameter and deliberately ignore it?

EDIT: It was my fault (as pointed out in the answer below) that I used a nil-self to initialize the object. However, the question kind of still holds. Because why do they state that target is set to *nil* when it actually isn't?

Comment: I think,
they said the target: Any?, - optional. For safely using, because otherwise if object deallocated the app will crash.

Comment: I am talking about this particular statement `A newly initialized item containing the specified system item. The item’s target is nil.` Both target and selector are optional. They say that only *target is nil*.

Comment: Maybe, this based on access level. Because I can get the target from UIBarButtonItem returned object, but I can't get the action selector of this object(private access).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

target nil, because you are set the target before controller init.
You should use something like this:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    var pauseItem: UIBarButtonItem? = nil
    var playItem: UIBarButtonItem? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        playItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .play, target: self, action: #selector(GameViewController.pauseButtonTouchUp))
        pauseItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .pause, target: self, action: #selector(GameViewController.pauseButtonTouchUp))
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely right. I didn't think of that! But there's a similar question to be asked. See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

#### Swift 3 (Xcode 8.3.3)

In Swift 3 you can get around this problem by declaring the properties as `lazy var` instead of `let`, however you must also be explicit about the data type of the property instead of relying on the inferred type because otherwise the `target` will again be set to `nil` due to some quirk of the compiler.

```
This is required ----------+
                           |
                           v
lazy var pauseItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
    barButtonSystemItem: .pause, 
    target: self, 
    action: #selector(GameViewController.pauseButtonTouchUp)
)
```

I have no idea why this happens, but it does.